# Response code 200 but navigator console displayes Error Parsing

Tags: angular, http, nestjs

first of all, am using angular as frontend and nest js as backend
the goal of this application is to ficilitate routers configuration (cisco, juniper, ... ) using a web interface which is the angular
i kept the calculation and all the work for the backend, so i just change to device wanted and the script of configuration will be generated based on what is inserted in the angular interface, like the name, interfaces configurations etc....
the problem is here :
i create a route for generating the script as text file like this :

```
generateConfigFile() {

    return this.http.get(`${this.API_BASE_LINK}/cisco/getScript`);

  }
```

this is a function in angular service that is called by function in a controller to send http get request to the backend to generate the script : NB all the data are stored in object at the backend

this is the backend controller code that supposed to return the file.txt contains the script

```
@Get('getScript') downloadConfigFile(@Res() res : Response) {
        let fileContent: string;
        let filename: string;
        const result =  this.ciscoConfigExtractorService.downloadConfigFile();
        fileContent = result.fileContent;
        filename = result.filename;
        const filepath = path.join(path.join(process.cwd(), 'files'), filename);
        fs.writeFile(filepath, fileContent, (err) => {
            if (err) {
                console.error(err);
                res.status(500).send('Failed to save file.');
                return;
            }
            // Return the file to the user
            res.contentType('text/plain');
            res.download(filepath, fileContent);
        });
```

this name of the file depends the name of the router that we configure

here eveything is good, even the file at the body response exist, but when i try to download it at the angular backend an error occures , this is it

```
{
    "headers": {
        "normalizedNames": {},
        "lazyUpdate": null
    },
    "status": 200,
    "statusText": "OK",
    "url": "http://localhost:3000/cisco/getScript",
    "ok": false,
    "name": "HttpErrorResponse",
    "message": "Http failure during parsing for http://localhost:3000/cisco/getScript",
    "error": {
        "error": {},
        "text": "\n!\nversion 12.2\nno service timestamps log datetime msec\nno service timestamps debug datetime msec\n service password-encryption\n!\nhostname R1\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\nip cef\nno ipv6 cef\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n ip domain-lookup\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\ninterface FastEthernet0/0\n \n ip address 41.1.1.14 255.255.255.252\n \n auto\n auto\n clock rate -1\n \n,!\ninterface FastEthernet1/0\n \n ip address 192.168.25.97 255.255.255.224\n \n auto\n auto\n clock rate -1\n \n,!\ninterface Serial2/0\n \n ip address 192.168.25.129 255.255.255.252\n \n \n \n clock rate 64000\n \n,!\ninterface Serial3/0\n \n ip address 192.168.25.137 255.255.255.252\n ipv6 address 2001:db8:acad::1/64\n \n \n clock rate 64000\n \n,!\ninterface FastEthernet4/0\n no ip address\n \n \n \n \n clock rate -1\n shutdown\n,!\ninterface FastEthernet5/0\n no ip address\n \n \n \n \n clock rate -1\n shutdown\n,!\ninterface FastEthernet0/0\n \n ip address 41.1.1.14 255.255.255.252\n \n auto\n auto\n clock rate -1\n \n,!\ninterface FastEthernet1/0\n \n ip address 192.168.25.97 255.255.255.224\n \n auto\n auto\n clock rate -1\n \n,!\ninterface Serial2/0\n \n ip address 192.168.25.129 255.255.255.252\n \n \n \n clock rate 64000\n \n,!\ninterface Serial3/0\n \n ip address 192.168.25.137 255.255.255.252\n ipv6 address 2001:db8:acad::1/64\n \n \n clock rate 64000\n \n,!\ninterface FastEthernet4/0\n no ip address\n \n \n \n \n clock rate -1\n shutdown\n,!\ninterface FastEthernet5/0\n no ip address\n \n \n \n \n clock rate -1\n shutdown\n\nip classless\n\nip route 192.168.25.64 255.255.255.224 FastEthernet0/0 192.168.25.138 1\n,\nip route 192.168.25.0 255.255.255.192  192.168.25.130 1\n,\nip route 192.168.25.64 255.255.255.224  192.168.25.130 5\n,\nip route 192.168.25.0 255.255.255.192  192.168.25.138 5\n,\nip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0  41.1.1.13 1\n,\nipv6 route 2001:db8:acad::1/64 Fa0/0   1\n,\nip route 192.168.25.64 255.255.255.224 FastEthernet0/0 192.168.25.138 1\n,\nip route 192.168.25.0 255.255.255.192  192.168.25.130 1\n,\nip route 192.168.25.64 255.255.255.224  192.168.25.130 5\n,\nip route 192.168.25.0 255.255.255.192  192.168.25.138 5\n,\nip route 0.0.0.0 0.0.0.0  41.1.1.13 1\n,\nipv6 route 2001:db8:acad::1/64 Fa0/0   1\n\n!\nip flow-export version 9\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\n!\nline con 0\n!\nline aux 0\n!\nline vty 0 4\n login\n!\n!\n!\n"
    }
}
```

please any advices or solution for my problem, even the ai couldn't help me

i want to make the configuration of routers easy, doesn't depend of the material just put your configuration in user friendly interface and the script will generated for you to be uploaded to the device

Answer (score 0):

As you're sending a text response from the server, you need to tell Angular to parse response as text as well by setting `responseType: 'text'` options.

Try making Angular request like this:

```
return this.http.get(`${this.API_BASE_LINK}/cisco/getScript`, { responseType: 'text' });
```

> responseType: 'arraybuffer' | 'blob' | 'json' | 'text'
>
> Read-Only
>
> The expected response type of the server.
>
> This is used to parse the response appropriately before returning it
> to the requestee.

https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpRequest#properties